# How can I setup compass on netbeans 7.4

Tags: netbeans, sass, netbeans-7, compass-sass

There is a feature in netbeans 7.4 that allows scss and less to auto compile on save.

I have managed to set up scss to compile but I am having problems compiling scss files using compass.

Here is an example error:

```
Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3.
          Load path: /www/site
    on line 2 of /www/site/app/View/Themed/Admin/webroot/scss/core.scss
```

Currently the compass is imported like so:

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

1. In NetBeans, click the File > Project Properties menu item.
2. In the dialog that opens, select the CSS Preprocessors category.
3. At the bottom of the Sass properties is Compiler options. Enter `--compass`

That fixed the problem you are asking about for me. However, I then encountered further problems with Compass because it was ignorant of the paths to files. To overcome this I created a config.rb file in the root of my project. This had to define a full project path and directory names. Moreover, working on a Windows machine, it was fussy about the direction of slashes and types of quotes.

```
project_path    = 'c:\path\to\project'
css_dir         = "css"
sass_dir        = "sass"
images_dir      = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
```

Comment: I didn't need to do the second part - working nicely on netbeans 8.0 on windows 8.1

Answer (score 3):

Another way that you can add Compass to all SASS projects without adding the argument to each project is by going to Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > CSS Preprocessors and adding " --compass" to the end of the Sass Path.

For example, mine reads "C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\sass.bat --compass".