# Useing imports with Sass and compass on netbeans

Tags: css, netbeans, sass, prestashop, compass

I am trying to get the Sass preprocessor to work on Netbeans using compass.

I have followed the advice in on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175866/how-can-i-setup-compass-on-netbeans-7-4) (adding --compass) to the compiler Options. This works for most of myfiles and Netbeans manages to compile them fine.

The problem I am encountering is if I have a .scss file in a subdirectory of the main sass folder which references a file to import that is located in the root sass e.g.

file:

```
sassroot/subdir/style.scss
```

with

```
@import "theme_variables";
```

which is referenceing

```
sassroot/_theme_variables.scss
```

When netbeans trys to compile this style.scss file it will give an error such as:

```
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: theme_variables
```

If i use relative paths for the import e.g.:

```
@import "../theme_variables";
```

It works however the project I am working on is a [Prestashop](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop) theme which uses this setup as default and I am reluctant to go making changes all over.

Workarounds:

1. Currently I am using [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) to compile the files which seems to work.

However I also have the netbeans project set to copy to another location on save. Because Koala is modifying the files independently it means this does not happen. As such I would rather use the compiler via Netbeans.

2. Change all the paths.

I would rather not do this as I want to keep the theme as default as possible and i'm pretty sure there is a way to get this to work in the config.rb file otherwise Koala wouldn't work.

3. Get Koala to work on the copy dir files.

This would make it harder for me to investigate the css files in my project as they would not be updated. (I guess I could get it do do both paths).

Any help is appreciated, thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

For thoses who have got the same problem, I found a solution that works for me.

1. In the netBeans project, go to "Project Properties"
2. CSS Preprocessors
3. In the sass Compiler Options field, add the "**--load-path** PATH" option

For exemple, Compiler Options : --compass --load-path C:\Path\to\prestashop\themes\mytheme\sass\